# create a Join in SQL tables

Tags: mysql, database, join

the assignment is :

> find the actors duo that get the most revenue per movie together since 2010 who were in cast order lower than 3 not belonging to collection and not as just  a voice and at least 3 movies together.
>
> hint : create a table with all the possible duos by self joining the tables on itself to get all the duos from the same movie.

can anyone please make me understand this hint? i can understand the self join but how to find the duos?

i have two tables movies and cast in movies table i have names of movies ,movie_id , revenue, character, belong to the collection and in cast table, i have movie_id, cast name, order .

```
select name,`order`,id from cast_id ci 
where  `order`<=3 and `character` NOT LIKE '%voice%'
```

after this i have all the actors with order less than equal to 3
, character not like voice and movie_id which is unique from here what to do to get duos?

Comment: A self-join creates all possible of a pairings of rows from an original table. Code a self cross join & look at the input vs output. Keep the pairs you want via ON or WHERE.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular formatted initialization.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to provide more information to get a proper answer, but if you had a table like this:

```
cast(MovieID,ActorID)
```

then you would do something  like

```
select c1.MoveID, c1.ActorID, c2.ActorID
from cast c1
join cast c2 on c2.MoveID=c1.MoveID and c1.ActorID>c2.ActorID
```

This will give you all the duos. The ">" means each pair only appears once, rather than once in each order. Depending on the reat of your requirements you might want to use "!=" instead.

Rest of the homework is up to you.

Comment: Great. Happy to give hints for your homework, as long as its not full answers you are after! Please remember to accept the answer if you are happy with it.